# Detecting where a submit event came from with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I need to detect how a user submitted a form to generate some statistics. They can either press enter when typing on the input or they could click the submit button.

I tried binding a click event to the button and a `keyup` event to the input but what happens is when I press enter the click event is triggered. I read in some other thread that this is part of the new HTML5 spec or something like that.

I then thought of binding a submit event to the form and detecting there what originated that event, but I've had no luck so far. Is that even possible?

**EDIT**

I guess I managed to fix it. I changed my `keyup` event to keypress, like suggested by fortegente, and prevented the `defaultEvents` from firing while at the same time triggering a submit event on the form. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: why does it really matter to you whether user uses keyboard or mouse (or touch) to submit?

Comment: Because the people running the site want to know that, I'm just the programmer assigned to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can try add custom attribute. Something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('event'));
});

$("button").on('click', function() {
   $("form").prop("event", "click").submit();
});      

$("input").on('keypress', function() {
   if (e.which == 13) {
     $("form").prop("event", "keypress").submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how that would help. I mean, the click event would still be triggered when I pressed enter (not only that, it appears to be triggered before the keyup event), and I would end up in the same situation. Or wouldn't I?

Comment: I set `click` event on the button and `keypress` event on the input. I call `submit` form when one of these events is called and before this I set 'event' property to identify what event was called. Therefore I send form. And in form `submit` handler event you can check this property and see button or enter called submit form.   
I hope it will be more clear)